# Passing an ng-model's selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

I am trying to filter some results using the selected value from an ng-select (stripping out formatting and other irrelevant information) I have:

```
<select ng-model="medium" ng-options="medium as medium.name for medium in mediaList" ng-change="loadSubMediums(medium)"></select>
```

Here, the loadSubMediums function takes medium with its properties and console.logs the correct medium that I choose. For reference to something working the way I expected:

```
<input type="text" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchText" />
```

This ng-model is "searchText" and works excellent to filter this ng-repeat:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="artist in featured | filter:searchText | filter:medium.name">
```

The problem is the second filter. I've tried variations on `medium`, `medium.name`, `{{medium.name}}`, trying to access the `$scope`. I have spend so much time banging my head on the wall, and it seems like it could be so straight forward.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please try to improve your formatting, so your question is easier to read.
I.e. you could wrap cited code portions in ``. I.e. `{{medium.name}}`

Comment: try changing `ng-model="medium"` to `ng-model="myMedium"` then use `filter: myMedium.name`

Comment: I tried this suggestion and didn't get any errors, but the filter is still not working.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Seems to work as expected. AngularJS version?

Comment: Checked my package.json and got "angular": "~1.4.0"

Comment: Is this the behavior you want? http://plnkr.co/edit/LCIwh6eR4M3P2BcvE5nK?p=preview

Comment: Yes, from what I can tell that is the exact behavior I desire.  The main difference I can see is where the ng-controller is on yours example.  And it not in my example.

Comment: Can you show the entire involved HTML?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses: https://github.com/bkentropy/culturalyst-yeoman/blob/master/client/app/discovery/discovery.html
I made a gist but the indentation looks terrible. (https://gist.github.com/bkentropy/5a5d5708251623742b39)

Comment: Thanks, will take a look.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but there seems to be a `</div>` too much. Just a note.

Comment: Is this correct? http://plnkr.co/edit/IwvetYNB0tLVWcLZGG50?p=preview

Comment: You are the best thank you! It looks like you included everything in the Discovery Ctrl, that's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I was trying to do:

> Is this correct? plnkr.co/edit/IwvetYNB0tLVWcLZGG50?p=preview